# Scroll to top of parent page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a form in an iframe, when its submitted I need it to scroll to the top of the parent page. I've tried a few different solutions with JS/jQuery but no success. I also tried adding onLoad to the iframe tag. Currently I'm using window.parent in a function, example is here: http://www.moneycorp.com/uk/personal/General-Enquiry-Test/

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appending the following code to iframe should work

`onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"`